# Redirecting visitors correctly (PHP and Regex)

Tags: php, regex, redirect, preg-match

I want if my visitors go to `subdomain.example.com` that they get redirected to `anothersubdomain.example.com`. And if they go to `css.subdomain.example.com` that they get redirected to `css.anothersubdomain.example.com` etc.

I've tried the following regexes (with preg_match):

**Attempt 1:**

```
if(preg_match('#(([\w\.-]+)\.subdomain|subdomain)\.example\.com#', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $match)) {
    header('Location: http://'.$match[1].'anothersubdomain.example.com/');
}
```

If they go to: `subdomain.example.com` they get redirected to: `anothersubdomain.example.com`

But If they go to: `css.subdomain.example.com` they get redirected also to: `subdomain.example.com` - So that is not working

**Attempt 2:**

```
if(preg_match('#([\w\.-]+)\.subdomain\.example\.com#', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $match)) {
    header('Location: http://'.$match[1].'.anothersubdomain.example.com/');
}
```

If they go to: `css.subdomain.example.com` they get redirected to: `css.anothersubdomain.example.com`

But If they go to: `subdomain.example.com` they get redirected to: `.subdomain.example.com` - And that URL is not valid so also this attempt is not working.

Somebody has an answer? I want not to use nginx or apache rewrites.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [worked for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6gltvR):

```
$tests = array(
    'subdomain.example.com' => 'anothersubdomain.example.com',
    'css.subdomain.example.com' => 'css.anothersubdomain.example.com'
);

foreach( $tests as $test => $correct_answer) {
    $result = preg_replace( '#(\w+\.)?subdomain\.example\.com#', '$1anothersubdomain.example.com', $test);
    if( strcmp( $result, $correct_answer) === 0) echo "PASS\n";
}
```

What I did is made the capturing group for the "first" subdomain optional. So, if you printed out the results like so:

```
foreach( $tests as $test => $correct_answer) {
        $result = preg_replace( '#(\w+\.)?subdomain\.example\.com#', '$1anothersubdomain.example.com', $test);
    echo 'Input:    ' . $test . "\n" . 
         'Expected: ' . $correct_answer . "\n" . 
         'Actual  : ' .$result . "\n\n";
}
```

You'd get [as output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kV11PE):

```
Input:    subdomain.example.com
Expected: anothersubdomain.example.com
Actual  : anothersubdomain.example.com

Input:    css.subdomain.example.com
Expected: css.anothersubdomain.example.com
Actual  : css.anothersubdomain.example.com
```

Now to apply it to your needs:

```
if( preg_match( '#(\w+\.)?subdomain\.example\.com#', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $matches)) {
    echo header( 'Location: http://'. (isset( $matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '') .'anothersubdomain.example.com/');
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! I've too small reputation but otherwise +1

Comment: @nickb Only 1 thing what about a subdomain with the 'hyphen character' (css-test.example.com)? And a subdomain with double dot (subdomain.subdomain.example.com)?

Comment: Just need to add the hyphen into the capturing group `(\w+\.-)`. What is the difference between `subdomain.subdomain.example.com` and `css.subdomain.example.com`?

Comment: @nickb Thanks! For me it is unnecessary but double subdomains does exits, you can easily add it in cPanel or any other site configuration software.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('#(\w*\.?)subdomain\.example\.com#', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $match)) {
    header('Location: http://'.$match[1].'anothersubdomain.example.com/');
}
```

Comment: [This will fail](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ECx33k) if there is a single subdomain whose suffix is `subdomain`.